# How to enrich documents in index in kibana/opensearch?

Tags: opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

Let's say I have pretty simple event-centric index:

```
{
  event: 'name',
  timestamp: 12345,
  user: 'some-id'
}
```

I have "registration" event, and want to enrich all events from this user with registration date. What's the easiest way to achieve it?
I bet I can do it somehow with help of transform API, but my best shot is to have entity-centric index of "users" like this:

```
{
  user: 'some-id',
  events: [...]
}
```

But then I will lose an ability to visualize, because I'll basically lose time field of my original index

Comment: Are you running Elasticsearch or Opensearch as they are two different products?

Comment: @Val I'm running opensearch, but so far any problem I had to encounter were solved in easier way with Elasticsearch docs/advices

Comment: Well, Opensearch is a fork of ES 7.10.2, so anything that happens after that version is not Opensearch anymore. The Opensearch documentation will probably improve over time, but I'd be very careful when trying to use Elasticsearch documentation 
and thinking that it will work with Opensearch.